# Uniform convergence a.e. does not imply convergence in mean

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

According to my notes: \begin{align}
f_n \rightarrow f  \text{ u.a.e} \nRightarrow f_n \rightarrow f \text{ in }L^1 
\end{align}
but if $ \mu(\Omega)<\infty$ and $ f \in L^1(\Omega)$, then the implication holds. I'm not sure why it is not sufficient $ \mu(\Omega)<\infty $, since I was not able to find an example in which $ f_n \rightarrow f  \text{ u.a.e} \text{ but } f_n \nrightarrow f \text{ in }L^1$ in this case. I should find an example in which $ f_n \rightarrow f $ u.a.e. but $ f \notin L^1. $ The only way I've thought to find an example is to find a series whose uniform limit is not measurable, so I was thinking to use Vitali's set but I could not find anything.

Comment: If $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$, then $f$ is a measurable function in $L^1$.

Comment: Yes, I did a bit of confusion in the question. I have to find an example of $ f_n \rightarrow f  u.a.e.$ but  $f_n  \not\rightarrow f $ in $L^1$, when $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.

Comment: what does u.a.e. mean?

Comment: Uniform almost everywhere, i.e. the essential supremum goes to 0.

Comment: if you mean almost uniform convergence, then an example is $f_n = \frac{1}{x}1_{(\frac{1}{n},1)}$ and $f = \frac{1}{x}1_{(0,1)}$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a set of measure $\epsilon$ so that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ outside this set of measure $\epsilon$

Comment: oh, then $f_n \to f$ u.a.e. does imply $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$. Take $\epsilon > 0$, then $N$ so that $n \ge N$ implies $||f-f_n||_\infty < \epsilon$. Then $n \ge N$ implies $\int_\Omega |f-f_n| \le \epsilon\mu(\Omega)$

Comment: Yes, I've done this. Maybe  the notes are just ambiguous and they mean the implication is not true for $\mu(\Omega)=\infty$. I was thinking it was possible to construct a limit of measurable functions  which is not measurable, but that is not possible, since the pointwise limit is measurable, and uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.

Comment: It might just be because since $L^1(\Omega)$ is a Banach space, if $f \not \in L^1$ then no Cauchy sequence can converge to it. Hence why we require it.